# What does the fourth number refer to here？

Tags: ambiguity

John locked his bike with a 4-digit combination lock several months ago, and he cannot recall the
correct combination. Each digit is one of the numbers 0, 1, 2, ..., 9. John only knows that each of the numbers 1, 4, and 6 appears exactly once, but he can’t remember
the position of those numbers, and he does not know which one of the 0-9 is the fourth number.

Can the fourth number refer to the combination's 4th position number or the 1,4,6 list 4th number?

Comment: It refers to the combination's 4th position.

Comment: Not the way I read it, @KillingTime.

Comment: There are 4 ***numbers**,* in 4 ***positions**.* So far as I can tell, this question is simply asking whether "the fourth number" in the cited text refers to the number whose value is unknown (in addition to the 3 numbers whose values are known to be 1,4,6) or to the number  ***in the fourth position*** (which could be any of the 4 making up the combination). Where pragmatically, only the first option seems credible.

Comment: Do we say that the number refer to the fourth number in 14,6, lsit because it is closer in distance ot the 4th number ?

Comment: Try [puzzling.se] ;)

Comment: @FumbleFingers What do u mean pragmatically, some other people also thought of the exact different.

Comment: @SelwynLiu: On one level, this isn't really anything to do with language (English or otherwise). It's a matter of straightforward logic. But on reflection it seems to me that [Grice's maxims](https://www.sas.upenn.edu/~haroldfs/dravling/grice.html) (relating to language) are key here. We have 3 *digits* (1,4,6) explicitly identified, and the only reference to *positions* (first,second,...) is "fourth". It's simply implausible that a speaker would choose to use that unqualified ordinal to mean *fourth **position*** rather than the contextually  implied *fourth [remaining unknown] **digit***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  But it is still possible, although could be out of context?

Comment: Also, the speaker could have said the "other number" instead of giving an order that people do not usually say when saying numbers u know or not know. Order should be given to sequences that are more relevant.

Comment: @SelwynLiu: Asking whether it's *possible* that "fourth" in this context refers to the rightmost of 4 *positions* on the lock, rather than to the remaining unknown digit (3 having been already identified) is like asking whether it's *possible* to interpret *John insulted my brother, so I hit **him*** as meaning that I hit my brother, rather than that I hit John. Syntactically speaking, such perverse interpretations are possible, but in practice *they will always be wrong*. If the "unusual" meaning was actually intended, a native speaker would simply find a clearer way of expressing it.

Answer (score 2):

It says that "he can’t remember the position of those numbers, and he does not know which one of the 0-9 is the fourth number".

It would be perverse for that to mean that he knows that those three numbers occur among first three positions, and so that number he can't remember must be fourth in the sequence.

The normal reading is "He can remember three of the numbers, but not the fourth", saying nothing at all about position of the number he can't remember.

Comment: But maybe it says that he is not sure of the number that is in hte 4th position, the fourth nuber could indicate the number in 4th position.

Comment: That is *not* what it says, @SelwynLiu

Comment: The number in the 4th position does not indicate that 1,4,6 have to be in front three. This sort of meant that the number has to satisfy both conditions that it has to be the 4th unknown and has to be in 4th position.

Comment: @SelwynLiu: There is no reference anywhere to a number in the fourth position. I accept that in some language which isn't my native English "but not the fourth" might mean "the fourth position". But both I and Phil Sweet have made it clear that that is not how we understand it in English.

Comment: I think that the 4th number's reference is established at start and with detail of 0-9.

Comment: @SelwynLiu:since you seem keen to insist that you know the answer to the question you posed, I wonder why you ever posted it. This question has been closed as "opinion based" (not by me), so I see no point in engaging with you further.

Answer (score 1):

Fun question. The logic of this turned out a little longer than I expected. Here goes:

The whole statement only refers to four numbers that occur on a bike lock. It provides no other information whatsoever about the position of any of these numbers.

"0-9" is the range of integer numbers from 0 to 9, so "*which one of the 0-9 is the fourth number*" refers to a number that exists in the set of numbers {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}.

We read that 1,4 and 6 each occur once, in unknown positions. That leaves the fourth number to come from the reduced set {0,2,3,5,7,8,9}. Its position too is unknown.

"can’t remember the position of those numbers" refers to the unknown positions of {1,4,6} in the lock.

"*the fourth number*" refers unequivocally to a number, to be understood as a number from the reduced set {0,2,3,5,7,8,9}. Being a number, it is *not* a position. Call it X.

X might happen to be the number in the fourth position (it has a 1/4 chance of being there) but we don't know any of the positions, so we cannot with certainty refer to X as being the number in the fourth position; it may be in any of the other three.

X must therefore be understood as the fourth number under consideration in the lock set {1,4,6,X}.

Comment: Does X have to be 4th number in 1,4,6? It can also be the 4th position number

Comment: No, it's not necessarily in the 4th position. It's one of x146 x164 x416 x461 x614 x641 1x46 1x64 ... 614x.

Comment: @rajah9 indeed yes. I did not think it necessary to set out such non-linguistic  detail in my answer, but you are correct. There are (4x3x2x1=24) such ways of arranging the numbers in the lock, of which only 6 end in X. Furthermore, X is one of seven possibilities, so John has only 7x24 =168 combinations to try - quite a lot of finger twiddling, but feasible!

Comment: Agreed, it sounds like a combinatorics problem and I think he should have the answer.